# styling HTML form list box with CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, listbox

I want to simply change the colors and define the edges of a multiple line select box, or list box.

I have seen a few threads on similar subjects, but not quite the solutions I am looking for. I need to be able to:

- Change hover color of elements
- Change select color of elements
- Change border
- Style side slider (not essential)

I think I might have to use JS (via jQuery, if possible), but would much rather use CSS is I can.

[Here is what I mean by a list box](http://jsfiddle.net/GRLwg/)

Comment: there is no possibility to do this just with CSS. Take a look at this plugin: https://github.com/vladfr/jquery-coolmultiple

Comment: the select box looks nice, but doesn't send the original values to the submit!!

Comment: @n3on this worked, add it as an answer to I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no possibility to do this just with CSS. Take a look at this plugin: github.com/vladfr/jquery-coolmultiple

Answer (score 3):

Try these

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/

http://www.adamcoulombe.info/lab/jquery/select-box/

**EDIT:**

Use this [jQuery SelectBox](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuerySelectBox) plugin

The output will be like [this](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/selectBox/)

Comment: none of these seem to support listbox's, they are all drop down select boxes.

Comment: There is no html element called as listbox and u need to add the attribute `size` to make it look like list box...

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear. Here is the code in question http://jsfiddle.net/GRLwg/

Comment: Yes, You have used the select boxes only .. As i told u have used the size attribute along with the tag.. If that's the case , my examples will work

Comment: I am probably going to branch what I have an try this tomorrow, but could you take a look at the other question I have (regarding the use of the coolMultiple plugin) and tell me if I will run into the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806917/affecting-select-values-to-fit-in-an-untouchable-system