# How do you customize the font in a GWT list box?

Tags: gwt

Using GWT 2.3 and new to all this..

How to you make the word "Select..." in italic and gray below?
I tried to setStyleName, but settings are ignore.

Thanks, Bob

```
// show word select in am empty list box.     nestUnderListBox.addItem("Select...");
```

// This line did not make "Select..." gray italic.
nestUnderListBox.setStyleName("nextUnderListBoxInitial");

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do isn't possible with CSS!

See [styling HTML form list box with CSS or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802926/styling-html-form-list-box-with-css-or-jquery) for other Ideas!

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with ListBox.

But, you can use something like CellList [(GWT-Showcase)](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) and re-develop the functionality from ListBox.